# How to store data name instead of it's value from html into my SQL database?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I'm trying to build a calorie loss calculator and getting the users current weight, in either pounds or kilograms, and the time they've been exercising for, in either minutes or hours. 
I want to save the data names (Pounds/Kilograms and Minutes/Hours) instead of their number values into my SQL database.

```
<?php
//session_start();

if (ISSET($_POST['savecalories'])) {
    session_start();
    $currentweight =     floatVal(mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Weight']));
    $weightunit = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['WeightUnit']);
    $activitytime = floatVal(mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Time']));
    $timeunit = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['TimeUnit']);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP code will just insert whatever the 'value' of the WeightUnit and TimeUnit select fields are (set as 1 and 2.2 for WeightUnit for example). I don't know what else your page/code does but simply you'd change the 'value' of the fields to be the words "Pounds or Kilograms".

But i'll assume you are doing other JavaScript calculations on the HTML page needing those "1" and "2.2" values. If that's the case, one way around this would be to change the value on the PHP page like below. This isn't the only option but is simple enough.

```
if (ISSET($_POST['savecalories'])) {
session_start();
$currentweight =     floatVal(mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Weight']));
if (mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['WeightUnit']) == '1') $weightunit = 'Pounds'; else $weightunit = 'Kilograms';
//$weightunit = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['WeightUnit']);
$activitytime = floatVal(mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Time']));
if (mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['TimeUnit']) == '60') $timeunit = 'Minutes'; else $timeunit = 'Hours';
//$timeunit = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['TimeUnit']);
$activity = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Activity']);
$calories = floatVal(mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Calories']));
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

 $query = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO tracklog
                  (currentweight,weightunit,activitytime,timeunit,activity,calories,userid)
                  VALUES('".$currentweight."', '".$weightunit."', '".$activitytime."', '".$timeunit."','".$activity."', '".$calories."', '".$userid."')");
}
```

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've just tried it but now nothing gets saved to my sql database :/

Comment: What type of MySQL field is the weightunit and timeunit columns? Varchar? Integer? Was it at least inserting anything before the above code change?

Comment: Both Varchar. Yeah, it was inserting the numeric values for both. But now it's saying there's a token mismatch.

Comment: That's odd. Try reverting the changes back to original and try the insert, does it work? Just want to rule out a different issue masked as coming from this latest change. All we did was a basic if statement to set a variable value.

Comment: Just tried it and it works! I just had to restart my SQL as I had restarted my mamp server before checking if the changes were working.